# Cassandra multiple datacenters with the same nodes

Tags: database, cassandra, datastax

I'm new in Cassandra. 
I have one cluster with one data center and three nodes. I want to know if I can use the same three nodes with a different data center in the same cluster using a different keyspace. This is because I want to use the same cluster for two different services at the same time.
Is it possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

You can have several keyspaces in the same cluster, if that what you trying to achieve.

What is a purpose of several clusters on same nodes?

You can configure keyspace that it will be saved within specific datacenter, or change replication factors for each datacenter, but it doesn't looks like you're searching for this solution. You can also play with IPs and ports and create 2 (or more) separate clusters running on same machines, but i don't see any benefit you can get from such configuration.

Comment: I have one service that uses Cassandra with one cluster and 3 nodes. Now I want to run another service and I wanna use the same machines. For the new service, can I use the same cluster and the same nodes with a different datacenter? Or do I have to configure a new Cassandra environment? My purpouse is to use the same machines and not configure other new nodes. I would share my machines for my two services.

Comment: Why do you need another Data center?Just use same machines, same cluster, same datacenter, just with another/additional keyspace.

Comment: It is not recommended , but you can do so

Comment: Still doesn't answer the question, can a server be a part of different datacenters?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to install any new cassandra instances or add another datacenter - just create new keyspace and point your application to it and using the same nodes.

So from application side you'll have something like this:

`app1 -> cassandra1 (DC1)     keyspace1
         cassandra2 (DC1)  -> 
 app2 -> cassandra3 (dc1)     keyspace2`